# Pandas: Aggregate of DataFrameGroupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I am working with this data set [census.csv](https://github.com/Qian-Han/coursera-Applied-Data-Science-with-Python/blob/master/Introduction-to-Data-Science-in-Python/original_data/census.csv)

Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Data/census.csv')
df = df[df['SUMLEV']==50]

print(df.head())
```

This is how my data looks like:

```
   SUMLEV  REGION  DIVISION  ...  RNETMIG2013  RNETMIG2014 RNETMIG2015
1      50       3         6  ...    -2.722002     2.592270   -2.187333
2      50       3         6  ...    22.727626    20.317142   18.293499
3      50       3         6  ...    -7.167664    -3.978583  -10.543299
4      50       3         6  ...    -5.403729     0.754533    1.107861
5      50       3         6  ...    -1.402476    -1.577232   -0.884411
```

I wanted to take the aggregate of two columns after grouping by 'STNAME':

```
(df.set_index('STNAME').groupby(level=0)['POPESTIMATE2010','POPESTIMATE2011'].agg(Avg= np.average, Sum = np.sum))
```

Error:

```
----> 3 (df.set_index('STNAME').groupby(level=0)['POPESTIMATE2010','POPESTIMATE2011'].agg(Avg= np.average, Sum = np.sum))

f:\software_installations\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in aggregate(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    922         elif func is None:
    923             # nicer error message
--> 924             raise TypeError("Must provide 'func' or tuples of '(column, aggfunc).")
    925 
    926         func = _maybe_mangle_lambdas(func)

TypeError: Must provide 'func' or tuples of '(column, aggfunc).
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*While others were fast to give the one-liner code snippet, I try to explain a bit more about kind of options you have, and what is the syntax understood by the pandas `agg()` function.*

### What are we dealing with?

The type of the object you are dealing with is

```
type(df.set_index('STNAME').groupby(level=0)[['POPESTIMATE2010','POPESTIMATE2011']])
# pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy
```

Therefore, it might be a good start to time look at the documentation of the [pandas.DataFrameGroupby.agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html)

### What do the docs say?

The argument given to `agg` can be

```
(1) string (function name)
(2) function
(3) list of functions
(4) dict of column  names -> functions (or list of functions).
```

#### (1) string (function name)

If you give function name string as the argument, it must be a "function name that pandas understands". Understood function names are at least: `'sum','mean','std'`. Example:

```py
In [24]: df.set_index('STNAME').groupby(level=0)[['POPESTIMATE2010','POPESTIMATE2011']].agg('mean')
Out[24]:
                      POPESTIMATE2010  POPESTIMATE2011
STNAME
Alabama                  71420.313433     71658.328358
Alaska                   24621.413793     24921.379310
Arizona                 427213.866667    431248.800000
...
```

*Since you want two things to be calculated: mean and sum, you need two function calls. One with 'mean' and one with 'sum'.*

#### (2) function

You can also give any function as an argument. The function should take array-like data (pd.Series) as input, and produce scalar value out of it. Example:

```py
In [25]: df.set_index('STNAME').groupby(level=0)[['POPESTIMATE2010','POPESTIMATE2011']].agg(np.mean)
Out[25]:
                      POPESTIMATE2010  POPESTIMATE2011
STNAME
Alabama                  71420.313433     71658.328358
Alaska                   24621.413793     24921.379310
...
```

*Since you want two things to be calculated: mean and sum, you need two function calls. One with np.mean and one with np.sum.*

#### (3) list of functions

You may also give a list of functions for the argument for `agg()`. Example:

```py
In [27]: df.set_index('STNAME').groupby(level=0)[['POPESTIMATE2010','POPESTIMATE2011']].agg([np.mean, np.sum])
Out[27]:
                     POPESTIMATE2010           POPESTIMATE2011
                                mean       sum            mean       sum
STNAME
Alabama                 71420.313433   4785161    71658.328358   4801108
Alaska                  24621.413793    714021    24921.379310    722720
Arizona                427213.866667   6408208   431248.800000   6468732
...
```

*This has the upside that you need only one function call. **Use this, if you want the same operations to be calculated with multiple columns***

#### (4) Dict to column names -> functions

If you give a dictionary as the argument to `agg()`, then the **keys** must represent the **column names** in the dataframe, and the values should be either functions or **lists of functions**. Example:

```
In [30]: In [27]: df.set_index('STNAME').groupby(level=0)[['POPESTIMATE2010','POPESTIMATE2011']].agg({"POPESTIMATE2010": [np.mean, np.sum], "POPESTIMATE2011": [np.mean, np.sum]})
Out[30]:
                     POPESTIMATE2010           POPESTIMATE2011
                             average       sum            mean       sum
STNAME
Alabama                 71420.313433   4785161    71658.328358   4801108
Alaska                  24621.413793    714021    24921.379310    722720
Arizona                427213.866667   6408208   431248.800000   6468732
...
```

*This has the upside that you need only one function call. **Use this, if you want different operations to be calculated with different columns***

Comment: Impressive, appreciate the effort.

Comment: You explained every option with a use case which is exactly what i needed to understand. Thanks!

Comment: Would be nice to wrap the example to 70 or 88 characters using additional outer parenthesis if needed.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
df.groupby('STNAME')[['POPESTIMATE2010','POPESTIMATE2011']].agg(['mean', 'sum'])
```

Note that you need double square bracket after groupby in this case.

Comment: No, you need one pair of brackets `[]` to access the columns. Inside the bracket, you need to pass either a column or a **list** of columns. Here, you want a list, so you need two pairs.

Comment: This works! But its also working with single bracket as well.

Comment: I was also surprised it worked with a single pair of brackets (using pandas 0.24.2). I don't know if it is a feature of `groupby()` which makes this possible, since accessing `df['POPESTIMATE2010','POPESTIMATE2011']` will raise a KeyError (as expected) .

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
import numpy as np

df.set_index('STNAME').groupby(level=0).agg(
    {"POPESTIMATE2010": [np.average, np.sum], "POPESTIMATE2011": [np.average, np.sum]})
```

Answer (score 0):

As you see the Error it clearly saying that we have to specify a function or tuples of (column,aggfunc).

Following is the correct way to call agg function

```
df.set_index('STNAME').groupby(level=0)[['POPESTIMATE2010','POPESTIMATE2011']].agg(['mean','sum'])
```

if you  notice the  double bracket after groupby ( [[ ]]) that because panda suggest that otherwise, you will get the warning like below

```
FutureWarning: Indexing with multiple keys (implicitly converted to a tuple of keys) will be deprecated, use a list instead.
```

also, you are using np.avarage that will give warming for empty slices like below :

```
RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
```